# Alternating bihomomorphism is skew of 2-cocycle - relative situation

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, quadratic-forms, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. It is well-known that every alternating  bihomomorphism $\Omega:G\times G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ (i.e. $\Omega(g,g)=1$) arises as the skew $\kappa/\kappa^T$ of a 2-cocycle $\kappa \in Z^2(G)$, where $\kappa/\kappa^T$ depends only on the cohomology class of $\kappa$.

In my situation, $\Omega:G\times G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ is a bihomomorphism and $T:=\{\;t\in G \; | \; \Omega(g+t,g+t)=\Omega(g,g) \quad \forall g \in G \; \} \subseteq G$. In particular, $\Omega$ is alternating on $T$. I would like that the following statement is true:

There is a 2-cochain $\kappa \in C^2(G)$, s.t. $d\kappa(g_1,g_2,g_3)=1$ if one of the arguments is in $T$ and moreover, $\Omega(g_1,g_2)=\kappa/\kappa^T(g_1,g_2)$ again if one of the arguments is in $T$.

Is such a result known or is it similar to something you know?